# Problem extracting email attachment using munpack

Tags: email, procmail, fetchmail

I have fetchmail running perfectly to fetch emails from Gmail, and then I am using procmail to store them in `$HOME/Mail/Inbox`. In my `.procmailrc`, I added this code which pipes to `munpack` to extract the attachment which can be a PDF or CSV file:

```
ATTACH=`echo $HOME/Mail/Inbox` 
:0 c
* ^To:.*me@email.com
* ^From:.*me@email.com
| munpack -q -C $ATTACH
```

But I don't get any file in /var/tmp or anywhere else. Also if I use munpack manually in terminal I get the error of "Did not find anything to unpack from /Users/[username]/Mail/Inbox".

Does anyone have any experience how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure about that `$HOME/[username]` bit? That would mean a directory inside your home directory which itself is called with your username, i.e. something like `/Users/esi/esi/Mail/Inbox`.

Comment: Gilles you are right! That should be $HOME/Mail/Inbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! Munpack will work just in case you have one mail in your mailbox text file. If you have more than that munpack will not work!

Comment: I had a related [question](http://superuser.com/a/187142/978) that turned into a script I shared on my [website](https://antipaucity.com/2014/04/24/automatically-extract-email-attachments-with-common-linux-tools) .. didn't know `munpack` only worked on a single email in your inbox at a time, however